# Web-Scraping using R (I want to extract some table like data from a website)

Tags: html, r, xml, web-scraping, rvest

I'm having some problems scraping data from a website. I do have not a lot of experience with web-scraping. My intended plan is to scrape some data using R from the following website: https://www.myfxbook.com/forex-broker-swaps

More precisely, I want to extract the Forex Brokers Swap Comparison for all the available pairs.

My idea so far:

```
  library(XML)
  url <- paste0("https://www.myfxbook.com/forex-broker-swaps")
  source <- readLines(url, encoding = "UTF-8")
  parsed_doc <- htmlParse(source, encoding = "UTF-8")
  test<-xpathSApply(parsed_doc, path = '/html/body/div[3]/div[6]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div', xmlValue)
```

But this doesn't bring up the intended information. Some help would be really appreciated here! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
h <- read_html("https://www.myfxbook.com/forex-broker-swaps")
h %>% html_table() %>% 
  purrr::pluck(3) %>% 
  setNames(paste(names(.), .[1,], sep="_")) %>% 
  rename("Broker" = "_Broker") %>% 
  filter(Broker != "Broker") %>%
  mutate(across(-Broker, as.numeric))
#> # A tibble: 91 × 13
#>    Broker          `EUR/USD_Short` `EUR/USD_Long` `EUR/USD_Type` `GBP/USD_Short`
#>    <chr>                     <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>           <dbl>
#>  1 Axi                        0.17          -0.56              0           -0.18
#>  2 Tickmill                   0.24          -0.55              0           -0.22
#>  3 Blueberry Mark…            0.31          -0.55              0           -0.17
#>  4 Eightcap                   0.31          -0.55              0           -0.17
#>  5 Rakuten Securi…            0.19          -0.5               0            0   
#>  6 ACY Securities            -0.34          -3.75              3           -1.28
#>  7 AAAFx                      1.98          -6.42              1           -2.07
#>  8 MultiBank Group            0.3           -0.66              0           -0.12
#>  9 Just2Trade                 0.12          -0.9               0           -0.26
#> 10 Fusion Markets             0.31          -0.55              0           -0.15
#> # … with 81 more rows, and 8 more variables: `GBP/USD_Long` <dbl>,
#> #   `GBP/USD_Type` <dbl>, `USD/CAD_Short` <dbl>, `USD/CAD_Long` <dbl>,
#> #   `USD/CAD_Type` <dbl>, `USD/JPY_Short` <dbl>, `USD/JPY_Long` <dbl>,
#> #   `USD/JPY_Type` <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot @DaveArmstrong for this. Is it possible to export the rest FX pairs? the web bage allows only 5 per view.  The full xpath for selecting other pairs is: "/html/body/div[3]/div[6]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/a/i"